# Compare property that can be a timestamp or FALSE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

having a property on Users that is FALSE when a user is still active or having a timestamp when a user left I want to catch users that are present during a timewindow. I understood that Cypher doesnt have date comparison to ask e.g. for BETWEEN (month/year) AND (month/year) so I put timestamps on the properties.

I tried to get the user by this query:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.end_date IS FALSE OR u.end_date > 1422658800 RETURN u
```

This should return all users that are still active (end_date = FALSE) or if the end_date is beyond the current timestamp (here 1422658800).

Unfortunately I stuck as NEO4J claims: Don't know how to compare that. Left: false (Boolean); Right: 1422658800 (Long)

I hoped it would either accept the Boolean or the Integer, but it seems to check both conditions and fails when comparing Boolean to Long Integer - which is fine.

Any idea how I could build a query that can handle both criteria so I can filter the correct users?

Thanks,
Balael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just not store the end_date if it was not set, just remove the property.

Then you can use:

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE coalesce(u.end_date,2^32) > 1422658800 
RETURN u
```

If you want to stick with your model, **which I do not encourage**.
You can turn your boolean into a number first.

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE (case u.end_date when false 2^32 else n.foo end)
      > 1422658800 
RETURN u
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will change the model, thats easier :)